# Sanitize location.hash

Tags: javascript, xss

We are using checkmarx to run security analysis, in the below function checkmarx highlight location.hash and it says severity of Client_DOM_XSS.
How to properly sanitize **location.hash** to prevent attacks in the below scenario

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                results = regex.exec(**location.hash**);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    var ec = getParameterByName('errCode');
    var en = getParameterByName('errorName');
    var em = getParameterByName('errorMessage');


    var el = document.getElementsByClassName("txtErrMsg");
    var msg = (ec == '' ? '' : ec + ' | ') + (en == '' ? '' : en + ' | ') + (em == '' ? '' : em + ' | ');

    if(msg.length > 3){
        msg = msg.substring(0, msg.length - 3);
    }
    el[0].innerHTML = msg;
    el[1].innerHTML = msg;
```

Provide any references/solution to this problem

Comment: use `el[0].textContent=` instead of `el[0].innerHTML=`, and it won't matter if one slips past your RegExp goalie. if you expect numbers, then `Number(strUntrustworthy)` returns a benign result.

Comment: This makes sense, but can we add any function that will check for any malicious scripts included in location.hash

Comment: maybe, but i sure wouldn't count on it...